# Disable tabs in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

### I have:

[image]

### I want:

[image]

Second image is taken from PhpStorm.

Is it possible to disable tabs like that in Visual Studio 2015? Resharper, plugins — everything works.